# astype does not work for Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called messages where data looks like

```
message             length  class
hello, Come here      16     A
hi, how are you       15     A 
what is it            10     B
maybe tomorrow        14     A
```

When i do

```
messages.dtypes
```

It shows me

```
class      object
message    object
Length      int64
dtype: object
```

Then I tried converting message column to string type

```
messages['message'] = messages['message'].astype(str)
print messages.dtypes
```

It still shows me

```
class      object
message    object
Length      int64
dtype: object
```

What am I doing wrong. Why doesn't it convert to string?

Python version 2.7.9 On windows 10 
Pandas version 0.15.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "string" datatype.  In pandas, strings are stored as objects.

In numpy, you can have string datatypes, but they're fixed-length, so there's still no "string datatype".  There's a datatype for 5-character strings, a datatype for 10-character strings, etc., but no datatype for "strings" per se.  Pandas uses `object` as the datatype for strings so that you can perform size-changing manipulations on the strings (e.g., concatenating them with other strings) without having to recreate the entire column with a new string length.

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax: But note that that example still gives a result that has dtype `object`.  You can use it, but it won't create anything of dtype `str`, as the OP found.